# Trying to make a stone wall- Cycles has weird glitch where it doesn't "fill in" the image texture even though evee does

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

[image]

Trying to make a stone wall..   essentially a blend of

1. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AWGoOuVFJwc - using cell fracture and various displacement/subsurface modifiers
2. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yiBktrx_MdE   - then using this to get the stone texture.

it's so very close to being what i'm after apart from these annoying glitches.

Also, if anyone can add an easy node to lighten the stones that would be great.

Thanks all

[image]

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=PnqVMZj9" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/PnqVMZj9/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gaps are generated by *Displacement* node in your shader. Eevee doesn't because doesn't use displacement feature. Changing *Scale* value to zero in Cycles does the same what Eevee looks like.

I'm not sure, but I would say you can use only **Bump Only** Displacement type with combination of UV texture. Any edge of UV will generate gaps, because blender doesn't know how to stick these parts of images.

[image]

[image]

Also it seems quite enough disable *Displacement* and use only **Normal Map** node with *Strength* like 10.

Comment: Amazing!! Thank you so much... this website is insane how everyone can answer these questions so quickly. hopefully one day i'll be able to answer someone elses questions